# smpt django on production server

Tags: django

I deploy my django project and my contact form stoped work. I tried some tips find on stack, but it doesn't works, help me plz.

Here my local settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mymail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

and my view:

```
def contact_form(request):

    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)    
    if form.is_valid():
        message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email') 
        subject = 'contact form'
        from_email = email
        to_email = (settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,)
        contact_message = '%s, from %s' %(message, from_email)

        send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=False)
        form = ContactForm()
        request.session.set_expiry(10)
        request.session['pause'] = True

    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Now when I send message I have "Internal Server Error".

Comment: what does the error log say?

Comment: 1 minute plz, it my was my first deploy. Need to understand, where I can find log

Comment: how did you deploy your app? nginx + uwsgi?

Comment: you can also look into nginx error log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Baterson via Skype and solved this issue together. the production server didnot support smtp settings and there were some other bugs. So we fixed them all and finally decided to just use:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

all is working now